# How does a C++ compiler compile variable names?

Tags: c++, variables, compiler-construction

I understand I did not make myself clear. My doubt, I think, could be summed up in this:

In an executable file(machine code) how are "variables" represented? Are they static memory addresses? Does the compiler gives each one a specific "name" (or just keeps the one you gave them)?

Expressed in code:

```
 int x=5;
 //Bunch of code
 cin>>y;
 cout<<x+1;
```

How does the program in each and every machine knows which address is going to hold the value 5, to hold the inputed value, to add 1 to the value it now holds and finally print that same value.

--João

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple program in C:

```
int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;

    int c = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile it with `gcc -m32 -S -O0 -o main.s main.c` under Linux, you'll get something like this

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    /* %ebp is a Base Pointer Register */
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp

    /* Here we reserve space for our variables */
    subl    $16, %esp

    /* a's address is %ebp - 4 */
    movl    $5, -4(%ebp)

    /* b's address is %ebp - 8 */
    movl    $7, -8(%ebp)

    /* a + b */
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    -4(%ebp), %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax

    /* c's address is %ebp - 12 */
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)

    /* return 0 */
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

As you can see, in this case, variables' addresses are calculated as offsets of a base pointer of a function. If you enable optimisations, variables' values may be stored in registers.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. You went through the trouble of explaining the inside asm code to me. You did not only answer my question but satisfied my curiosity and made me want to learn assembly. Kudos to you Sr.

Comment: Just one more thing if it is not too much to ask for. Do those offsets mean for example: %ebp -12 = less 12 addresses counting from the base one?

Comment: @JoãoSilva if %ebp is 0xffffcfe8, c's address will be 0xffffcfe8 - 4 = 0xffffcfdc, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @JoãoSilva I'd also recommend this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: @kharvd did you actually compile it to assembly, or just produce that ASM yourself? If you wrote the ASM, you sir, are a legend.

Comment: @Brett Surely I just used GCC and did some cleanup afterwards. It's not so difficult to write such simple logic in assembly language by hand, though.

Answer (score 8):

It's implementation-specific.

Typically, the location of variables will be based on all sorts of factors and optimizations.  They may not live in RAM at all, as they may be optimised to live entirely within registers, or optimised away entirely.

Variable names don't exist at run-time; they're discarded during compilation.  However, the compiler may emit debug information that's stored in the application binary, to allow the developers to debug the application.  This is usually removed in release versions, though.

I have no idea about the specifics of Gameshark.  But in many cases, the location of a particular variable can be figured out by taking a look at the machine code for the application.

Comment: Your whole post wasn't showing. I'm sorry. About the variables: How what does the compiler do to var names. About Cheat Database question: You say the location of a variable can be figured out by the machine code? does that mean a variable is always given the same address?

Comment: @JoãoSilva: Your original question doesn't really make sense, the compiler doesn't "compile variable names".  My answer is an attempt at explaining what I think you want to know.

Comment: @JoãoSilva The compiler throws  away variable names.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not always, the linker may need them

Comment: @DavidHeffernan then how does the what to print in a case similar to this:
int a;
cin>>a;
//Bunch of code
cout<<a;

Comment: @Seth Alright then. Let's try again. The compile/link phase throws away names.

Comment: @JoãoSilva That question does not make any sense

Comment: I pressed enter by mistake read it again.

Comment: @JoãoSilva: Re "is a variable always given the same address?".  It's complicated.  On older platforms, if you and I both run the exact same application, then a particular variable will live at the same location in (virtual) memory.  On modern systems, features such as [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) affect things.

Comment: Damn! That was hard! That was exactly the kind of answer i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: the program that runs on the machine knows where to find the variable that **you** call a, but it does not know that you called it a.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the question is how...

Comment: So your question is, how does a compiler work?

Answer (score 1):

So there are two parts to this, and I'll do my best.

When compiling, a compiler will convert the C++ code into an internal representation. This is then converted into using the CPU's registers as efficiently as possible, and pushing the rest of the data into RAM. As the program executes, data from ram will get copied back and forth into registers.

On your other question, one method I've seen that people use for this is for the gold that a user has. A program could take the entire memory space of the game and copy it. Then, the user does something (a minimal action) to gain or lose gold. The external application then searches through the entire memory space for what values have changed, and what previously was the original amount of gold, and what is now the current amount of gold. Once they find this location, they are able to edit the memory location and update it with whatever value they want.

Generally, the more complicated the game is, the harder that method is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry to be so confused but imagine this: int a=5; a=6;your first explanation doesn't tell me how the program knows which value to change. On the other hand your second answer explains the process of searching for values in memory like cheatengine does. That I already knew. My question was about cheat databases which hold what look like adresses like if the same address always holds the same variable in any console(video game console) everytime the program runs. Sorry if I'm not clear. My english is just not helping me.

Comment: @JoãoSilva: Many systems are implementing [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) which would make that difficult.