# in c++ i cant select a specific variable for use with user input

Tags: c++, variables

I am trying to make a program where you can add an item to a list, and each item has a specific value, and at the end it tallies them all up, but I can't find a way to allow a user to type in the name of a variable and it identifies it for use! I have already attempted to use cin >> but that didn't work!

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: In c++, variable names are not known after compile time, so what you're asking for is impossible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351698/how-does-a-c-compiler-compile-variable-names?rq=1 for more detail.

Comment: if you tried to use `cin << ...` I'm not surprised it didn't work. Did you try `cin >> ...` ? (the var name issue is impossible, but I see no evidence you even did that, so you gotta start from somewhere). You may also consider you don't need a list for this task; all you need is a sum variable and a current value variable.

Comment: It can be done. Briefly on Linux: The code has to be compiled with debug info. Then read the name of the variable in the program and start a `gdb` connecting to the executable itself (if it does not work, start a script which starts gdb). The  value can be printed by gdb, quit then return from the script. But rather use a `map` instead of bare variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to name the input values. The code below will return the sum of all numbers entered. Enter a blank line to end the list of numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    std::string line;
    int sum = 0;

    while(true) {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);

        if (line.empty())
            break;

        int val;
        std::istringstream(line) >> val;

        sum += val;
    }

    std::cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

If you do need to assign names to the input values for some reason, I suggest using a [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to use cin is `cin >> var;` not `cin << var;`. Also, I recommend not `using namespace std;` and do `std::cin >> var;`